# formula to increment date time value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have intial date time in this format
'2017-01-01 09:00:00.000'
I want to increment it by preferably by millisecond. Even second will do. I can't find formula for to increment Date time in particular format. 
What I found was Time(hours,minutes,seconds) but it does not work.

Comment: Not really clear where your problem is. To add a second to a date value, simply add `TIME(0,0,1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your date is in Cell A1. The formula to add 1 second would be =A1+1/86400. To add a millisecond would be =A1+1/86400000. To add 5 milliseconds would be A1+5/86400000

Comment: Worked perfectly for me in Google Sheets as well!